# Angular 15 Event Binding Type Object Does not Accept Specific Function Type Declaration

Tags: angular

In an angular 15 project, I have a component called in the html file by

```
<app-component
      (onAction)="action($event)">
</app-component>
```

and the invoked action function declared in the ts file as

```
action(event: { first_data_item: number; second_data_item: number; third_data_item: any; fourth_data_item: string }) {}
```

If enabling strict mode, I get error

```
Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ first_data_item: number; second_data_item: number; third_data_item: any; fourth_data_item: string }'.
```

Without strict mode enabled, this works like a charm.

How should I specify the data sent with this function call?

Comment: Can you include the .ts code also? What type does `onAction` have? What's the parameter type that you use for the `action` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of your function argument definition and your `$event` parameter must match.

We can't see how you have defined your `@Output() onAction` in your `app.component.ts` but my guess is it is something generic like:

```
@Output() onAction: {};
```

Therefore TypeScript complains that `onAction` may be emitting an object with **any** keys/values and your consuming `action()` function is expecting **specific** keys/values, specifically:

```
{
  first_data_item: number;
  second_data_item: number;
  third_data_item: any;
  fourth_data_item: string
}
```

To resolve this specific clash in isolation you have two options:

- Change your `onAction` type to match your `action` type, i.e. make `onAction` more specific
- Change your `action()` type to match your `onAction` type, i.e. make `action()` less specific

---

However, I assume from the term `action` you are trying to build a state management solution and have therefore intentionally loosely typed `onAction` and specifically typed `action` as you are expecting to have multiple actions with different payloads (objects). Therefore neither of the above solutions will work for you.

A better way of doing this would be to leverage [`discriminated union types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

`actions.ts`

```
type ActionOne = {
  type: 'actionOne',
  payload: {
    first_data_item: number;
    second_data_item: number;
    third_data_item: any;
    fourth_data_item: string
  }
}
type ActionTwo = {
  type: 'actionTwo',
  payload: {
    someOtherKey: any
  }
}

type Actions = ActionOne | ActionTwo
```

`app.component.ts`

```
@Output() onAction: Actions;
```

`other.component.html`

```
<app-component
  (onAction)="action($event)">
</app-component>
```

`other.component.ts`

```
action(event: Actions) {
  if (event.type === 'actionOne') {
    // It knows the type of payload is ActionOne['payload']
    event.payload.first_data_item // valid
    event.payload.someOtherKey // error
  }
  else {
    // It knows the type of payload is ActionTwo['payload']
    event.payload.first_data_item // error
    event.payload.someOtherKey // valid
  }
}
```